# Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando gerar algumas páginas através de um programa chamado `PHP Generator for MySQL` e estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro que não é possível, o site acessar normalmente com o Host passado pela hospedagem, mas no erro me aparece um outro número.
No `cpanel` o usuário criado está relacionado com o banco de dados como sugerido no momento da criação do mesmo.
Segue uma imagem da minha tentativa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O IP em `Host` é diferente do que mostra na mensagem, porque? Podes ter de usar um tunnel SSH, tens a opção para isso nas *Connection properties*.
Confirma que o user/password estão correctos e que o servidor permite ligações externas (vindas que não do servidor).

Comment: Olá @Leite, como posso ver pelo CPanel essa informação: "servidor permite ligações externas"?